# How can I render on ReactJS to html files(and their images) which stay on relative path?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am working on closed internet web application. Application's technologies are Java and ReactJS. I have some html sites directories and I should show to in the Modal as a website. But, It is not a single html page. HTML pages involve some images, icons and js files. There are also in the folder. 
If I download website directory to the folder on below the spring boot static file, after end of the use I delete the files. The way, I can connect to site `http://localhost:3000/websiteDirectory/index.html`
Is there a library I can use for the view html website on ReactJS?

I could not handle the problems with iframe or `dangerouslySetInnerHTML`.

React code:

```
 render() {
        return (<div>
                <Modal width={1300} footer={false} closable={true}
                       visible={this.state.visible} onCancel={this.closeModal}>
                    <Form>
                        <Iframe url="http://localhost:3000/webview/index.html"
                                allowFullScreen={true}
                                width="100%"
                                height="100%"
                                display="initial"
                                referrerpolicy={"same-origin"}
                                position="relative"/>
                          <div resource={""}
                        />
                    {/*<div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: this.state.htmlFile}} />*/}
                    </Form>
                </Modal>
            </div>


        );

    }
```

Comment: [`iframe` elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe) use `src`, not `url`, for the URL of the page to show.

Comment: I tried but, not work. :) I am getting some errors. 

Module parse failed: Unexpected token (1:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
| <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
| <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
|  <head id="Head1">